polars write_ipc file size issue
Polars consistently produces unexpectedly large ipc file sizes when persisting to disk. With  parquet, file sizes are comparable to pandas / slightly smaller as expected.
Rough ballpark of my problem: pandas feather: ~250MB - polars ipc: ~2.5GB
Most files get blown up between a factor 1.5x to 10x, and seems to scale with number of columns.
I do not think this is a pyarrow problem, as pandas produces the expected file size, give or take.
I don't think this a polars-python bug, I assume this is a me/my computer problem...
Maybe someone can help?
minimum viable code to reproduce:
import os
import yfinance
import polars as pl
import subprocess

os.environ["POLARS_VERBOSE"] = "1"

# datetime example
data = yfinance.download(
  tickers="^AXJO ^N225", start="2005-01-01", end="2024-06-01", interval="1d", threads=True, prepost=True
)
data.columns = data.columns.get_level_values(1) + "_" + data.columns.get_level_values(0)
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index, name="date_utc").tz_localize(None)
data = data.reset_index()

# both results in datetime[ns] / float64 for all columns
data.to_feather("banana.feather")
pl.DataFrame(data).write_ipc("banana_pl2.feather")

# integer example w larger data
data2 = {
  "vals1": range(50_000),
  "vals2": range(50_000),
  "vals3": range(50_000)
}

# disproving this is a pandas->polars artefact
pd.DataFrame(data2).to_feather("b.feather")
pl.DataFrame(data2).write_ipc("b_pl.feather")

command = "ls -lha | grep feather"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
>>>-rw-r--r--   1 xxx.xxx  884741199   589K Jun  9 11:41 b.feather
>>>-rw-r--r--   1 xxx.xxx  884741199   1.1M Jun  9 11:41 b_pl.feather
>>>-rw-r--r--   1 xxx.xxx  884741199   338K Jun  9 11:41 banana.feather
>>>-rw-r--r--   1 xxx.xxx  884741199   523K Jun  9 11:41 banana_pl.feather

I have gotten the same results for the following two configs:
--------Version info---------
Polars:               0.20.31
Index type:           UInt32
Platform:             macOS-13.6.5-arm64-arm-64bit
Python:               3.10.6 (main, Aug  7 2023, 13:38:39) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]

----Optional dependencies----
adbc_driver_manager:  <not installed>
cloudpickle:          3.0.0
connectorx:           <not installed>
deltalake:            <not installed>
fastexcel:            <not installed>
fsspec:               <not installed>
gevent:               <not installed>
hvplot:               <not installed>
matplotlib:           3.8.0
nest_asyncio:         1.5.8
numpy:                1.26.0
openpyxl:             3.1.2
pandas:               2.2.2
pyarrow:              16.1.0
pydantic:             <not installed>
pyiceberg:            <not installed>
pyxlsb:               <not installed>
sqlalchemy:           2.0.22
torch:                <not installed>
xlsx2csv:             <not installed>
xlsxwriter:           <not installed>

and
--------Version info---------
Polars:               0.20.19
Index type:           UInt32
Platform:             macOS-13.6.5-arm64-arm-64bit
Python:               3.10.6 (main, Aug  7 2023, 13:38:39) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]

----Optional dependencies----
adbc_driver_manager:  <not installed>
cloudpickle:          3.0.0
connectorx:           <not installed>
deltalake:            <not installed>
fastexcel:            <not installed>
fsspec:               <not installed>
gevent:               <not installed>
hvplot:               <not installed>
matplotlib:           3.8.0
nest_asyncio:         1.5.8
numpy:                1.26.0
openpyxl:             3.1.2
pandas:               2.1.1
pyarrow:              13.0.0
pydantic:             <not installed>
pyiceberg:            <not installed>
pyxlsb:               <not installed>
sqlalchemy:           2.0.22
xlsx2csv:             <not installed>
xlsxwriter:           <not installed>


Weird, I think I discovered the origin -  passing in the argument pl.DataFrame(...).write_ipc(...,compression="lz4") yields parity with pandas file sizes.
Both the docs for pandas & pyarrow state the default compression is None, but if on digs deeper, they actually state None=="lz4" ‍♀️

most of the times when a parameter is defaulted to None (I think) it's to avoid https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

By definition, the IPC format is not compressed by default. The IPC format is optimized for in memory analytics and zero copy, zero serialization and zero deserialization of data between processes. It's not optimized for disk storage. Actually you should expect the size of the file to be the same as the size of the table in memory pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(data).nbytes. If disk space is important, you should use parquet.
